# How the get all sets keys in redis sorted by its SCARD?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

I'm using redis for storing something like an inbox. Each key has the messages for a particular group.

And in rails I need to fetch it and bring the groups sorted by the messages count.

```
user:1:inbox:group:1: a, b, c
user:1:inbox:group:2: a, b
user:1:inbox:group:3: a

SCARD user:1:inbox:group:1 = 3
SCARD user:1:inbox:group:2 = 2
SCARD user:1:inbox:group:3 = 1
```

Again, I want to get all the group ids, in this case: 1, 2, 3, but they have to be in DESC order by its set count of elements. In other words, the groups with more messages will be in the first of the list.

I know I can do:

```
REDIS.keys("user:1:inbox:group:*")
```

and it returns an array of these keys. But can't figure if its possible or the right way to achieve that...

Any help and thoughts are welcome.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

IMPORTANT: don't use the KEYS command - it is meant for non-production purposes only. See [the doc page](http://redis.io/commands/keys), specifically:

> Warning: consider KEYS as a command that should only be used in production environments with extreme care. It may ruin performance when it is executed against large databases. This command is intended for debugging and special operations, such as changing your keyspace layout. Don't use KEYS in your regular application code.

Additionally, KEYS does not guarantee the order of results - as you've found out yourself :)

There are three possible approaches that I can suggest to address the challenge:

1. **Sorted Sets**: You can use a sorted set to store each user's inbox groups and and set each group's score to the cardinality/count (naively, `ZADD user:1:inbox:groups 3 "1" 2 "2" 1 "3"`). You can then use [ZRANGE](http://redis.io/commands/zrange)/[ZREVRANGE](http://redis.io/commands/zrevrange) and such to get back the results sorted.
2. **[SORT Command](http://redis.io/commands/sort)**: Redis' [SORT](http://redis.io/commands/sort) is quite powerful. For example, you can use a list/set for each user's groups and keep the weights (cardinality) in separate keys. Once done, you can retrieve the list with something like:

   SORT user:1:inbox:groups DESC BY user:1:inbox:group_card_*
3. **Do It Yourself**: Sometimes it is simpler/more effective to perform the sort **outside** the database. Of course, this is dependent on your data model and requirements, but note that both previous suggestions require Redis space and compute power, whereas the DIY approach can delegate some of the cost to the app/client.